# Oracle Free Cloud restore boot volume backup

Tags: backup, restore, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I wanted to try out the Oracle Free Cloud, but i have a problem with restoring a backup boot volume to the instance.

Is it possible to restore a boot volume backup and replace the current one from the instance?

At the moment i was only able to terminate the current instance and boot volume and create a new instance out of the backup. But then the public IP changed...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restore the backup directly to a running instance. You need to create a volume from the backup and use the same to boot your instance and it will change the Public IP. But you may prefer to use elastic IP if its allowed within the free tier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info about the elastic IP, didnt know that was a thing. I will try the reserved IP if thats possible and that would be enough for me and a solution that works for me. I am a bit irritated why it is not possible to restore and replace an existing boot volume or reassign another one to the instance. Thats what i would assume how it worked.

Tried the reserved IP, thats what i needed. I can now just assign and unassign the reserved ip for a newly created instance of a backup. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i am irritated by this too, its just a bit troublesome to detach, terminate the old boot volume, then create new boot volume using the backup and attach it back to the instance, 4 steps just to recover the backup lol